# Passing values back to views from django dynamic fields

Tags: python, django, forms

I have searched a lot for this answer, and I am sure it is something very basic I am missing. I want to pass an argument into a dynamic form in django. The form dynamically populates the ChoiceField based on the value passed to it but I get a key error for 'location_choice' when I submit the form.

The form gets passed a location_choice (which is actually a group), it then picks out a list of relevant locations based on that filter and populates the drop down with the values listed as the PK for each location. What I cannot do is then submit that form and pass that value back to a subsequent view. I cannot pass any data back as I get a key error

I have spent hours trying to understand what it is I am doing wrong here, including reading this post, which was helpful but I'm still missing something:

https://jacobian.org/writing/dynamic-form-generation/

views.py

```
def test_search(request):

    form = search_criteria(request.POST or None, location_choice="Group A")
    return render(request, 'utilisation/util_search_day_theatre.html', { 'form': form })
```

forms.py

```
class search_criteria(forms.Form):
    start_date = forms.DateField(label='Start Date', required = False, input_formats=['%d/%m/%y', '%d/%m/%Y'], initial="1/1/16")
    end_date = forms.DateField(label='End Date', required = False, input_formats=['%d/%m/%y', '%d/%m/%Y'], initial='1/5/16')
    dayofweek_dataset = dayofweek.objects.all().values_list()
    dayofweek_choice = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, label='Choose a Day of the Week:', choices= dayofweek_dataset, initial=2)


    def __init__(self, *args,**kwargs):
        self.location_choice= kwargs.pop('location_choice')
        super(search_criteria,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        location_query = locationslist.objects.filter(location_group__exact=self.location_choice).values_list('id','location').order_by('id').distinct()
        self.fields['location_choice']  = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, label='Choose a Location', choices= location_query)

    def location_choice(self):
        yield (self.fields[location_choice].label, value)
```

The source is showing me that the ChoiceField is populating the drop down menu as I would expect, with the correct PK for each individual location within a particular group.

When I submit the form I am getting a KeyError:

```
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py in inner
            response = get_response(request) ...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) ...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/Users/TD3/django/tass/utilisation/views.py in generic_render
        form_data = search_criteria(request.POST) ...
▶ Local vars
/Users/TD3/django/tass/utilisation/forms.py in __init__
        self.location_choice= kwargs.pop('location_choice') ...
▶ Local vars
```

the only thing there is in views.generic_render is a form validation step with an HttpResponse of 'success' if the form data is valid. I will build up that view once I can work out how to get the data into it as it will do a lot of other things with the form data. I currently works as several hardcoded views, with a separate view for each location_group. I just want to make it pythonic (as best I can) and have a generic search view and a generic display view

```
def generic_render(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_data = search_criteria(request.POST)
        if form_data.is_valid():
            return HttpResponse("Success")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Form data not valid")
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback. What is giving the KeyError?

Comment: Note however that you have used the name `location_choice` for both an attribute and a method; you can't do that in Python, one will overwrite the other.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited to show the full traceback.

Comment: That traceback is showing that you are using a completely different view from the one you have posted, ie `generic_render`.

Comment: I have added the generic_render view. It only exists as a form validation tool at the moment. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you're using two views here. But since you are, you need to remember to pass the `location_choice` parameter into the form from *both* of them.

```
form_data = search_criteria(request.POST, location_choice="Group A")
```

(Also note the point I mentioned in the comment: your form method `location_choice` is being overwritten by the attribute of the same name. I doubt you need that method, anyway.)

Comment: Thank you, that is blindingly obvious now you point it out. So the form checker needs the same inputs as the form to check it;s validity. I was seeing the "form_data" on the next view as an **output** only, rather than a feedback loop to check the **input**. Thank you so much I will sort out the views issue in due course. Apparently my votes don;t show, but my thanks here will.

Comment: No problem. I don't know why the votes don't show, but you should be able to click the green checkbox to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: I'm too much of a newbie. It counts but isn't shown.